# API Auth with firebase admin SDK (server to server) not (client to server)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a frontend app that authenticates with firebase. When our users login we can use their JWT token and pass it to our express backend which verifies their access. Now our API is secure and only users authenticated on the frontend can use our api.

```
const fbTokenHeader = req.headers['userjwt'];
const auth = req.firebase.auth();
const user = await auth.verifyIdToken(fbTokenHeader);
if(!user) throw `No editor account found for ${user.email}`;
next()
```

Now we need for our scheduler (just another backend app). It needs to use this api but of course it is not authenticated on the frontend. What is a secure way to allow access server to server?

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the token along to your scheduler server? You can either pass it along decoded (if you trust the connection) or pass it along encoded and re-verify/decode it on the destination server.

Comment: Creating the token in a way that actually authenticates the other device is unknown

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But looking at the code you added to your question, the approach I specify in my answer seems valid: you can either pass the encoded or decoded token along to the other server, based on whether the connection is secure.